# Weird bug when "innerHTML" is used..?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, innerhtml

I found a weird error that I could not understand. Can someone please explain why below code is not working? Button2 stops working when I put it inside of the `<div id='test'>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id='button1'>Button1</button>


<div id='test'>
    <button id='button2'>Button2</button>
</div>

<script>
//Global var
var content = document.getElementById('test');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').on('click', function(){
        content.innerHTML += '<hr>';
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button2').on('click', function(){
        content.innerHTML += ' Test';
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: since you replace the button element, then the event handler no longer applies

Comment: haven't checked, but from what I recall of this basically the `+= '<hr>'` really means that you are setting the innerHTML to the current innerHTML value, plus the new hr tag. This removes any event listeners. instead inside that document.ready call (which you don't need 2 of) do `$('#test').on('click', '#button2', function(){...})`

Comment: Try `$(content).append(' Test')` instead. Will keep all other elements original and not remove the event listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"event" is no longer valid when you change the element. Feed from the upper element to remain in the "event".

```
 $('#button2').on('click', function(){

 replace width:

 $('body').on('click', '#button2', function () {
```